# What can be measured or derived about a remote magnetic field?

Tags: magnetic-fields, measurements

*This question related to [Why are magnetic lines of force invisible?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/51554/why-are-magnetic-lines-of-force-invisible) and is motivated by a comment of @BlackbodyBlacklight, based on that, the illustrating example may depend on that linked question as context to be clearly understandable.*

A remote magnetic field, in the sense that it is not at the location of measurement, could influence the location of measurement in some (possibly indirect) way that allows to derive information about it's structure.

This is comparable to deriving information about a remote temperature profile based on properties of the local electromagnetic field, like when *using a camera*, or just *seeing something glow*.

It might well turn out that it is fundamentally impossible to derive information about a remote magnetic field, (given some sensible constraints).
In this case, an Answer should ideally explain why that is the case.

What is described above is roughly comparable to human perception, which was the context where the question came up originally. Therefore, I will illustrate my initial ideas in that context in the section below:

---

*Establishing the context for the question (The biological aspects referred to are part of the **illustration**, **not** directly related to the question):*

The motivating idea was: *"We can not see magnetic fields, but that may be because it was not important during evolution to acquire this capability."*

Could it be possible, in principle, to "see" magnetic fields?

Now, if it would have been helpful during evolution - what kind of 
perception is possible purely **from the physical side** of the question - assuming "perfect evolution".

The linked question asks about seeing magnetic field lines - so could something like eyes for *seeing field lines* have evolved?
I **assume not**, so we do not need to go into details whether to see them on surfaces, as lines at a fixed distance, etc. (Feel free to make creative assumptions as needed regarding how to "see")

What did evolve, in some birds and bacteria, is perception of the field of Earth in terms of **direction of the local(!) field** lines - something like "feeling north and south".

---

*The actual question, related to physics of magnetic fields, in comparison to phenomena for which human perception exists:*

What are the **physical constraints**?

Seeing a magnetic field like a fourth base color would not work - there is no radiation.

Something similar to spacial sound perception? Which would mean to measure from a finite set of "local" reference points to collect measurements on a given remote locatioin.

Anything better than measuring a local field vector is certainly interesting.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your question. What do you mean by *What are the physical limits?* You also state your question is about the *properties of magnetic fields,* but you don't really reference that concept in your question. It seems like you're asking about how it would "feel" to "sense" magnetic fields. If that's the case, it seems off topic.

Comment: @BMS I see your point, and am trying to clarify just that. I would like to understand reasons why 'perception of magnetic fields' just can not work - for some simple definitions of perception. It's about understanding the differences between magnetic fields and things we can perceive, light, sound - in this context.

Comment: @BMS Somehow, the question is a very direct spin off of the linked one. Without that as context, it is harder to see the point, probably.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a hypothetical situation about biology & perception and not physics.

Comment: @KyleKanos What I am trying to ask is neither hypothetical nor perception related; That's all part of giving a context for the actual question. But I see that this is not easy to see from the text, which somehow assumes too much context from the linked question.

Comment: @Volker: Your question is *What are the physical limits [for perceiving magnetic fields]?* This is entirely hypothetical (because it didn't happen and you are proposing a "what if") and completely off-topic on a site about *physics* (because it is about biology and perception).

Comment: @KyleKanos The answer of BlackbodyBlacklight is exactly the kind I am hoping for. But he also knows the linked question as context, not only this. I would need to rewrite the question independently of that linked one it seems.

Comment: @KyleKanos Yes, regarding the title, I formally agree, so there's a real problem I need to fix. In the previous comments, I was more thinking of the question body (implicitly), which has a similar, closely related problem, but not that severe - I'm working on that part.

Comment: @Volker: You still have not addressed the fact that this question is asking about something that is entirely hypothetical; this means it is [expressly off-topic](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) as per the site rules.

Comment: @KyleKanos My previous comment was trying to say that I now explicitly see what you mean, regarding the title. If you refer to the "actual question": The point is, that it's not about something hypothetical - it is about understanding/visualizing/relating physical some concepts around an example topic, broadly speaking. I think the "underlying" question is unusual in structure, and somewhat complex, but otherwise just "how does this make sense compared to that". Note I'm trying to explain my point, but am aware I did not succeed up to now.

Comment: @KyleKanos Could you take a quick look? Let me know if you feel a "Ah,  *that*'s what he's talking about"-moment, or not yet?

Comment: So now your question is, *Can one detect a magnetic source at some distance while in some ambient magnetic region?* Am I reading that correctly?

Comment: @KyleKanos Roughly speaking,, yes. But as I assume one can measure a magnetic field only at the location of measurement, not elsewhere, the answer to that as a plain question would have to be just "No". So I'm trying to include ideas/approaches/answers that at least give some approximate result, by possibly very indirect means - only excluding the method "just go over there and measure".

Comment: @KyleKanos The question has something like an exploratory aspect, as it's not really expecting to find a strict solution (and make some use of it), but more like expecting approximations, and lots of insight about the problem space on the way. Not sure how that formally matches the scope, but to me it feels like a valid approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sensing any kind of wave requires that it either impinge on the observer, or produce a local, temporary side-effect such as a phase change, which is then visible by affecting the propagation of other waves which impinge on the observer.

[image: A wave generates pressure, causing temporary condensation, which is visible.]

*A wave generates pressure, causing temporary condensation, wherein water droplets reflect visible light.*

[image]

*A wave affects its medium's density, altering the index of refraction and generating [caustics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caustic_%28optics%29) as directional light passes through.*

A sufficiently powerful magnetic field will ionize nearby molecules, due to local magnetic moments and those of elementary particles. That should produce a visible effect, although being close enough to see it would probably be lethal.

On a friendlier scale, iron filings trace magnetic field lines to make them visible, but this doesn't reveal the field strength very well. Some filings may stand on end where the field isn't perpendicular to the surface containing them, and it has sufficient strength.

Being able to sense the value of a field at a remote point without any intermediary would be "spooky action at a distance."

Comment: In the second case it's more a caustic than interference pattern, which is visible on the photo.

Comment: @Ruslan Thanks, I was in doubt about that. Updated!

Answer (score -3):

Good question and interesting discussion. But i am afraid it is still possible :)

Theoretically you can can have an alien bionic/machine creatures who have  particle  **accelerators** (mini/nano etc.) inside of them. This accelerators can be suited to see magnetic field almost similar way as with vision. BUT. Funny enough in this case it seems not possible to LOOK outside but only inside of the creature. Some kind of inner vision. Or. If the creature is allowed to constantly emit particles outside of it then also outside vision can be possible.

Off course this is just a sketchy guess. Details need to be elaborated.